# Python 3.6 - Do not include duplicate values in list using Counter

Tags: python, list, count, duplicates, conditional-statements

```
a = ['1','1','1','1','1','3','3','3','1','1','1','1','1']
b = ['4','8','3','1','7','6','4','9','8','3','2','5','2']

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(a)

c = []
d = []

for x, y in zip(a, b):
    if counts[x] == 5:
        c.append(x)
        d.append(y)
    if not counts[x] == 5:
       if counts[x] == 3:
           c.append(x)
           d.append(y)
    else:
        None
```

Initially the code will look through list A and then count whether there are any numbers that repeat 5 times. If there are 5 occurrences the code will append the number from list A and corresponding list B value.

Then another condition will be applied if there are 3 occurrences of a number in list A, the value and corresponding value from list B will be printed.

**Output**

```
# c = ['3','3','3']
```

However in my example I believe it gets confused in searching for the 5 occurrences if it repeats later on.

**Desired output**

```
# c = ['1','1','1','1','1','3','3','3']
```

How could I make it specify that it has to be exactly 5 occurrences from one instance?

---

```
a = ['1','1','1','1','1','3','3','3','1','1','1','1','1']
b = ['4','8','3','1','7','6','4','9','8','3','2','5','2']

counter, c, d = 1, [], []

a[-1] = ['-1']
b[-1] = ['-1']

for i,j in enumerate(a):
    if a[i-1]==a[i]:
        counter+=1

        if counter == 5 and a[i+1]!=a[i]:
            c += [j]*5
            d += b[i-4:i+1]
            counter = 1

        if counter == 3:
            c += [j]*3
            d += b[i-2:i+1]
            counter = 1   
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: You said to filter out, but then you're appending.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye reworded it now

Comment: Note that 1 repeats 10 times not 5 going by the `Counter`. Are you asking for contiguous repetitions?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye yes that's my problem, it should count as 5 times for the first instance but I want it to ignore the second instance

Comment: @MosesKoledoye if there are two instances of 5 occurrences, then only the first one would be counted

Comment: Your code doesn't produce any strange result, since '1' seems to appear 10 times - not 5.

Comment: @coder Hi, yes it appears 10 times but is there a way to make it ignore a second repeated instance? So that '1' appears as 5 times and ignores the second repeated instance.

Comment: @coder or is that impossible using the counter module?

Comment: counter module ignores the position of each item, just counts how many times it appears totally. If you want to search for consecutive repetitions counter won't help you.

Comment: @coder do you know of an alternative?

Comment: @F.Lee yes, iterate over the list and count it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could use a simple counter, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

a = ['1','1','1','1','1','3','3','3','1','1','1','1','1']
b = ['4','8','3','1','7','6','4','9','8','3','2','5','2']

counter, c, d = 1, [], []

# append non existing values in a,b such that not to count the 
# last consecutive series - in this case the '1's
# if you want to count the last 5 '1's then you can change the
# following lines to:
# a += ['-1'] and b += ['-1']

a[-1] = ['-1']
b[-1] = ['-1']

for i,j in enumerate(a):
    if a[i-1]==a[i]:
        counter+=1

        if counter == 3 and a[i+1]!=a[i]:
            c += [j]*3
            d += b[i-2:i+1]
            counter = 1

        elif counter == 5:
            c += [j]*5
            d += b[i-4:i+1]
            counter = 1   
    else:
        pass

print 'c list: {}'.format(c)
print 'd list: {}'.format(d)
```

This will produce the following result:

```
c list: ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '3', '3', '3']
d list: ['4', '8', '3', '1', '7', '6', '4', '9']
```

**Update**

If you want your c list not to contain duplicate values change the above code to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

a = ['1','1','1','1','1','3','3','3','1','1','1','1','1','4','4','4','2']
b = ['4','8','3','1','7','6','4','9','8','3','2','5','2','1','2','3','1']

counter, c, d = 1, [], []

a[-1] = ['-1']
b[-1] = ['-1']

for i,j in enumerate(a):
    if a[i-1]==a[i] and a[i] not in c:
        counter+=1

        if counter == 3 and a[i+1]!=a[i]:
            c += [j]*3
            d += b[i-2:i+1]
            counter = 1

        elif counter == 5:
            c += [j]*5
            d += b[i-4:i+1]
            counter = 1   
    else:
        pass

print 'c list: {}'.format(c)
print 'd list: {}'.format(d)
```

Result:

```
c list: ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4']
d list: ['4', '8', '3', '1', '7', '6', '4', '9', '1', '2', '3']
```

Have in mind that in this way your code makes more checks to see if the item is on the c-list, so is a bit more expensive than before.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153160/discussion-on-answer-by-coder-python-3-6-do-not-include-duplicate-values-in-li). If any relevant insights were gleaned from this discussion, they should be edited into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, here's a possible solution. Maybe could shorten it by using `itertools.groupby` or other tricks.

```
def find_group(l, group_len):
    i = 0
    while i < len(l):
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(l) and l[i] == l[j]:
            j += 1
            if j - i == group_len:
                return i
            i = j
    return None

a = ['1','1','1','1','1','3','3','3','1','1','1','1','1']
b = ['4','8','3','1','7','6','4','9','8','3','2','5','2']
start3 = find_group(a, 3)
start5 = find_group(a, 5)
c = []
d = []
if start5 is not None:
    c += a[start5:start5 + 5]
    d += b[start5:start5 + 5]

if start3 is not None:
    c += a[start3:start3 + 3]
    d += b[start3:start3 + 3]

print(c)
print(d)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, however when I use the code it seems to give me nothing for c and d?